# Google Sheets - Using Filter as an input to Sequence to find UNIQUE Dates

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Long time listener, first time caller....

I have multiple start and end dates for each of a few individuals. So something like:

```
Name   Start   End

Sam    5/1     5/5

Bob    5/3     5/7

Sam    5/3     5/10

Ralph  5/7     5/12

Bob    5/7     5/12

Ralph  5/15    5/17
```

And so on. As many as 13 start & end date entries per individual.

I need a count of unique dates within those entries. For Sam above, it would be 10: `5/1 - 5/10`. (Actually, I only need `9` - I skip 5/10.) For Bob it's `5/3 - 5/12` so `10`, and Ralph it's `9`.

I can use `FILTER` to obtain the list of dates:

```
=FILTER(Sheet2!D:E,Sheet2!P:P,"=Sam")
```

With the list of start (Col A below) and end (Col B below) dates in hand, I can go one-row-at-a-time and generate a unique array of dates (5/1, 5/2, 5/3, 5/4, 5/5....5/10) and count the unique entries. Sequence generates each date in an array based upon start and end date; `UNIQUE` cleans up the duplicates; `COUNT` gives me the number of unique dates:

```
=COUNT(ArrayFormula(UNIQUE({SEQUENCE(B1-A1,1,A1);IF(A2>0,SEQUENCE(B2-A2,1,A2),"");IF(A3>0,SEQUENCE(B3-A3,1,A3),"");IF(A4>0,SEQUENCE(B4-A4,1,A4),"")})))
```

(Formula shortened for brevity - would be 13 `SEQUENCE` items.)

What I can't figure out is how to combine this into a single formula, AND place the result beside a table with the name of each individual so I have a count of unique dates. The result would be:

```
Sam   10

Bob   10

Ralph 9
```

Any advice on the next steps to try? Perhaps `SEQUENCE` is the wrong way to analyze the overlapping dates?

(While a script would solve this with a FOR EACH in an array, would prefer a formula.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are right that Sequence is the way to go.

First of all, if there are no gaps it's trivial, just the max end date - min start date:

```
maxifs(C$2:C,A$2:A,E2)-minifs(B$2:B,A$2:A,E2)
```

But in the case where there are gaps (as with Ralph) and you don't want to count them, you can use Sequence to generate an array of dates spanning the start and end date, then use Countifs to check whether each of them falls within at least one of the pairs of dates in the data:

```
=ArrayFormula(
countif(
   countifs(A$2:A,E2,B$2:B,"<="&sequence(maxifs(C$2:C,A$2:A,E2)-minifs(B$2:B,A$2:A,E2),1,minifs(B$2:B,A$2:A,E2)),
                     C$2:C,">="&SEQUENCE(maxifs(C$2:C,A$2:A,E2)-minifs(B$2:B,A$2:A,E2),1,minifs(B$2:B,A$2:A,E2))),
">0")
)
```

[image]

**EDIT**

The above formula is inconsistent as mentioned in the comments because the range max to min is counted non-inclusively (omitting the last date in the range), while the separate sub-ranges (like Ralph's) are counted inclusively.

Non-inclusive formula (omitting last date):

```
=ArrayFormula(
countif(
   countifs(A$2:A,E2,B$2:B,"<"&sequence(maxifs(C$2:C,A$2:A,E2)-minifs(B$2:B,A$2:A,E2)+1,1,minifs(B$2:B,A$2:A,E2)),
C$2:C,">="&SEQUENCE(maxifs(C$2:C,A$2:A,E2)-minifs(B$2:B,A$2:A,E2)+1,1,minifs(B$2:B,A$2:A,E2))),
">0"))
```

Inclusive formula (including last date)

```
=ArrayFormula(
countif(
   countifs(A$2:A,E2,B$2:B,"<="&sequence(maxifs(C$2:C,A$2:A,E2)-minifs(B$2:B,A$2:A,E2)+1,1,minifs(B$2:B,A$2:A,E2)),
C$2:C,">="&SEQUENCE(maxifs(C$2:C,A$2:A,E2)-minifs(B$2:B,A$2:A,E2)+1,1,minifs(B$2:B,A$2:A,E2))),
">0"))
```

Comment: Yes I agree, the formula is inconsistent. I've made the max-min range non-inclusive by not adding one (so Sam is 10-1=9, not 10-1+1 which would be 10 if you include both the first and last date). But I haven't done the same thing for the individual pairs of dates like with Ralph, I'm counting 6 for the first pair and 2 for the last pair. To be honest I would have been happier if all the counting had been inclusive. Suppose Ralph's dates were 7 to 12 then 13 to 17 - it doesn't seem intuitive to me that you would then basically want a gap in the middle to get 5 + 4 rather than 6 + 5.

Comment: Having said all that, it's easy enough to adjust the formula so will do it both ways.

Comment: Really well done - never thought of max and min then back-tracking to check if a date is in Sequence. Unfortunately I've found a glitch. Sam is correct: 10-1 = 9. Bob is correct: 12 - 3 = 9. But Ralph is incorrect: (12-7)+(17-15) = 7. The formula shows 8. The reason is there is a gap in the dates. It adds 1 for each gap in the dates: 2 gaps between 3 pairs of dates, +2 over actual.

Solution I believe is to discard the last date in the range - the date listed in the "End" column C. To do this, just change the ">=" to ">". Do you agree Tom?

Comment: Yes, you're right, change <= to < but also add one to max-min to cover the whole range.